# NtFsControlFile function error

Tags: c, winapi, visual-c++

I have this code:

```
// page1.h

NTSTATUS (__stdcall *NtFsControlFile)( 
                    HANDLE FileHandle,
                    HANDLE Event,                   
                    PIO_APC_ROUTINE ApcRoutine,     
                    PVOID ApcContext,               
                    PIO_STATUS_BLOCK IoStatusBlock, 
                    ULONG FsControlCode,
                    PVOID InputBuffer,              
                    ULONG InputBufferLength,
                    PVOID OutputBuffer,     
                    ULONG OutputBufferLength
            );


ULONG (__stdcall *RtlNtStatusToDosError) (
        IN NTSTATUS Status
        );
```

Then at *page2.cpp*:

```
page2.cpp
VOID LocateNativeEntryPoints()
{
    //
    // If we're on Win9x, just return
    //
    if( GetVersion() >= 0x80000000) return;

    //
    // Load the NTDLL entry point we need
    //
    if( !(NtFsControlFile = (void *) GetProcAddress( GetModuleHandle(TEXT("ntdll.dll")),
            "NtFsControlFile" )) ) {

        _tprintf(TEXT("\nCould not find NtFsControlFile entry point in NTDLL.DLL\n"));
        exit(1);
    }
    if( !(RtlNtStatusToDosError = (void *) GetProcAddress( GetModuleHandle(TEXT("ntdll.dll")),
                            "RtlNtStatusToDosError" )) ) {

        _tprintf(TEXT("\nCould not find RtlNtStatusToDosError entry point in NTDLL.DLL\n"));
        exit(1);
    }
}
```

I have these errors at `if(!NtFsControlFile =  and if( !(RtlNtStatusToDosError =`,

```
error C2440: '=' : cannot convert from 'void *' to 'NTSTATUS (__stdcall *)(HANDLE,HANDLE,PIO_APC_ROUTINE,PVOID,PIO_STATUS_BLOCK,ULONG,PVOID,ULONG,PVOID,ULONG)'
         Conversion from 'void*' to pointer to non-'void' requires an explicit cast

error C2440: '=' : cannot convert from 'void *' to 'ULONG (__stdcall *)(NTSTATUS)'
         Conversion from 'void*' to pointer to non-'void' requires an explicit cast
```

The original *page2* was  C language file. I need to cast that and how to do it or how can I resolve the problem.

Thanks a lot.

SOLUTION THAT SEEMS TO WORK(NO AUTOMATICALLY CAST LIKE C LANGUAGE):

```
     // a typedef to make casting easier

    typedef NTSTATUS (__stdcall *NtFsControlFilePtr)(
        HANDLE FileHandle,
        HANDLE Event,
        PIO_APC_ROUTINE ApcRoutine,
        PVOID ApcContext,
        PIO_STATUS_BLOCK IoStatusBlock,
        ULONG FsControlCode,
        PVOID InputBuffer,
        ULONG InputBufferLength,
        PVOID OutputBuffer,
        ULONG OutputBufferLength);

// the actual pointer to function

NtFsControlFilePtr NtFsControlFile;

// and the GetProcAddress call

    if( !(NtFsControlFile = reinterpret_cast<NtFsControlFilePtr>( GetProcAddress( GetModuleHandle(TEXT("ntdll.dll")),
            "NtFsControlFile" ))) ) {

        _tprintf(TEXT("\nCould not find NtFsControlFile entry point in NTDLL.DLL\n"));
        exit(1);
    }
```

THIS SOLUTION WORKS BUT  YOU GET:

C4191: 'reinterpret_cast' : unsafe conversion

with /WALL

to avoid warning:

```
if( !(NtFsControlFile = reinterpret_cast<NtFsControlFilePtr>( reinterpret_cast< void* >( GetProcAddress( GetModuleHandle(TEXT("ntdll.dll")), 
        "NtFsControlFile" )))))  {

        _tprintf(TEXT("\nCould not find NtFsControlFile entry point in NTDLL.DLL\n"));
        exit(1);
    }

   if( !(RtlNtStatusToDosError = reinterpret_cast<RtlNtStatusToDosErrorPtr>( reinterpret_cast< void* >( GetProcAddress( GetModuleHandle(TEXT("ntdll.dll")), 
        "NtFsControlFile" )))))  {

        _tprintf(TEXT("\nCould not find NtFsControlFile entry point in NTDLL.DLL\n"));
        exit(1);
    }
```

Comment: Does really contain `page2.cpp` C++ code?

Answer (score 0):

If you have pure c code, you can change typecast a bit, I mean:

1. declare the variable:

   ```
   typedef NTSTATUS (__stdcall *NT_FS_CONTROL_FILE)(IN HANDLE FileHandle,
                         IN  HANDLE Event, IN PIO_APC_ROUTINE  ApcRoutine,
                         IN PVOID ApcContext, OUT PIO_STATUS_BLOCKIoStatusBlock,
                         IN ULONG FsControlCode, IN PVOID InputBuffer,
                         IN ULONG InputBufferLength, OUT  PVOID OutputBuffer,
                         IN ULONG OutputBufferLength);
   NT_FS_CONTROL_FILE nt_fs_control_file;
   ```

   Then you need

   ```
   nt_fs_control_file = GetProcAddress(
   ```

   or

   ```
   nt_fs_control_file = (NT_FS_CONTROL_FILE)GetProcAddress
   ```
2. To call your function:

   ```
   NTSTATUS status = nt_fs_control_file(....);
   ```